# How can I get elements of same id

Tags: html, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse html. Two tables has the same id in the same html. How can I parse this?

```
<div>
      <table width='450' border=4  id='1234azert'>
      ...
      </table>
      <table width='450' border=5  id='1234azert'>
      ...
      </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Two elements should never have the same ID.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java and C# ?

Comment: may be it would be  the better idea to change id to name

Comment: Parse in which language? C#? Java? JavaScript? And what exactly is the difficulty you are experiencing? You need to be a lot more specific.

Comment: yes, I know it is imposible. But I see. http://imageshack.us/f/542/sameid.png/

Comment: @DarrenDavies did you show image ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. If you use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) you can use [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) and set index of element wich you are need.

Answer (score -1):

The same ID can not be assigned to multiple elements. An ID is unique. A class however represents a group or collection and allows you to do what you want.

Answer (score -2):

It should never be the case. Two elements should never have the same id in any scenario. 
If you have such case, first element with that id in the dom tree is always returned.

More explanation here :

[Is it normal to have two elements with same id in two div elements with other id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093121/is-it-normal-to-have-two-elements-with-same-id-in-two-div-elements-with-other-id)