# Hide div tag using button with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, block, display

I've been searching for solutions all over Stack Overflow and I've even copied some simple code from W3Schools but both just don't seem to work.

This is my current code (simplified):

```
<script language="javascript">
  function remove() {
    document.getElementById('vraagkader').style.display = "none";
  }
</script>

<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="vraagkader" style="display: block">
    <?php
      echo "<form name='test'><input type='submit' name='5050' value='5050' onClick='remove()'></form>";
    ?>
  </div>
</body>
```

Now also:

```
<script language="javascript">
  function remove() {
    if (document.getElementById('vraagkader').style.display !== "none";) {
      document.getElementById('vraagkader').style.display = "none";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Doesn't work...

I've also tried setting it up in CSS first and then tried editing it with JavaScript like:

```
#vraagkader {
  display: block;
}
```

And then with the same JavaScript but that also doesn't work.

Now all of it just doesn't seem to work for some reason. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Any errors in the console? At least the second version should give you a parse error...

Comment: Youre not doing anything to prevent the form from being submitted. You also have a typo (extra `;`) in `document.getElementById('vraagkader').style.display !== "none";`. And we don't need to see the PHP, just the rendered HTML.

Comment: Why do you have a form?

Comment: Sorry but you code is working.Tested here:http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/zvi3-85x6 (press F9)

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira no, it doesn't. it reloads, thus re-showing the div.

Comment: Editing your question to a new question after it has been answered isn't allowed, Please ask a new question. Note however that the question you were trying to ask with your edit is a duplicate. Please try searching first. (you can't have duplicate ID's on a web page)

Comment: I can't find it? Do you have a link? @KevinB

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093121/is-it-normal-to-have-two-elements-with-same-id-in-two-div-elements-with-other-id/3093136#3093136

Comment: Here's more: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%22duplicate+id%22+is%3Aanswer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your button is a "submit". When you click it, it reloads the page. Granted, it also deletes the div, your code works. But the page reloads immediately, so it's regenerated faster than your eye can see. Change `type="submit"` to `type="button"` and you should be fine.

http://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/VpzWMW

Comment: Why the silent downvote?

Comment: Works for me +1

Comment: The code posted by the OP is working.

Comment: No it's not, check out my codepen link. When you click the submit button, it reloads it all.

Comment: Oh.. That actually did the trick, never knew there was a difference between the two, thank you! :)

Answer (score -1):

```js
function remove() {
    document.getElementById('vraagkader').style.display = "none";
 return false;
  }
```

```html
 <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="vraagkader" style="display: block">
      <form name='test'><input type='submit' name='5050' value='5050' onClick='return remove()'></form>
    </div>
  </body>
```