# How to load multiple CKEditor toolbars on the same web page

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ckeditor

I have two divs on the same page using CKEditor.  I can get a toolbar to load for the first div, but not the second.  I realize this is the case because I'm using an id for ckToolbar instead of a class.  However, if I use a class, the toolbar doesn't show up.

**Div 1**

```
<div id="ckEditor">
    <div id="ckToolbar"></div>
    <div class="editor" data-bind="wysiwyg: txtBody, value:txtBody, valueUpdate:'keydown'"></div>
</div>
```

**Div 2**

```
<div id="ckEditor">
    <div id="ckToolbar"></div>
    <div class="editor" data-bind="wysiwyg: txtHelpText, value:txtHelpText, valueUpdate:'keydown'"></div>
</div>
```

**Config.js**

```
config.extraPlugins = 'sharedspace';
config.sharedSpaces = { top: 'ckToolbar' };
```

I am also using Knockout JS.  I created a custom binding and a div instead of a textarea because I couldn't use the CKEDITOR replace function with my binding.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two elements on the same page with same `id's`. [How is JavaScript supposed to recognize which one you have in mind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093121/is-it-normal-to-have-two-elements-with-same-id-in-two-div-elements-with-other-id/3093134)? You should either use `classes` or different `id's` and adjust you knockout code to handle that.

Sorry for the general answer but there is simply no way around it. You can't have two elements with same `id` on a single page.

NOTE: [CKEditor auto replaces](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_framed.html#alternative-methods-for-creating-a-classic-editor) elements with `ckeditor` class however if you are using knockout, I don't think this will me much of a use for you.